# How can I get the offset of an element within an SVG document?

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I get the display offset of an SVG element within the SVG document?  In particular, I'm trying to load an SVG image into memory as a separate document and get the offset of an element within the SVG document.

```
let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`
  <svg>
    <g id="layer1">
      <rect
        id="rect1"
        style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.67619;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
        class="hub hub-container"
        width="352"
        height="117.33334"
        x="0.19999915"
        y="0.19999835"/>
    </g>
  </svg>`,
  "image/svg+xml"
);

let rect = content.querySelector("g.port_1");

let offset = ?
```

I've seen methods that use `SVGGraphicsElement.getCTM()` to get the transform matrix of the `<g>` tag but this method doesn't seem to be available on an SVG image that's been loaded in the way shown above.

Edit: Or, as an alternative way of asking the same thing, why doesn't this print two transform matrices:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" style="width: 100vw; height: 50vh;">
      <g>
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.67619;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       class="hub"
       width="352"
       height="117.33334"
       x="0.19999915"
       y="0.19999835"
       id="rect14" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="script-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let g = document.body.querySelector("g");
      let rect = g.querySelector("rect");
      console.log(g.getCTM());
      let svg = `
        <svg width="1000" height="1000" style="width: 100vw; height: 50vh;">
      <g class="test-class">
        <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.67619;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       class="hub"
       width="352"
       height="117.33334"
       x="0.19999915"
       y="0.19999835"
       id="rect14" />
      </g>
    </svg>
      `;
      let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg, "image/svg+xml");
      document.querySelector("div.script-container").appendChild(content.documentElement);
      let g2 = document.body.querySelector("g.test-class");
      console.log(g2.getCTM());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome 115, this prints the first transform matrix but then gives `Uncaught TypeError: g2.getCTM is not a function`.

Comment: If you log `g` to console, it _shows_ a `g` there - whereas logging `g2`, results in an `SVGMatrix` output. Must have something to do with the parser or appending the resulting documentElement - because if I replace that part with just `document.querySelector("div.script-container").innerHTML = svg;`, then `g2` logs as a `g` object as well afterwards.

Comment: To whoever commented to point out the missing namespace, and whoever identified the duplicate question:  Thank you.